# Unable to pull package with Composer version 2.*

Tags: docker, composer-php, magento2, http2

I'm building docker image for Magento2 e-shop where we use some packages from [magefan.com](https://magefan.com). Problem is that I'm unable to pull packages from [magefan.com](https://magefan.com) while building the image. The problem occurs only when using Composer version > `2` where it ends with following error.

```
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                                                                                                                                                 
The 'https://***:***@magefan.com/repo/packages/download/package/magefan-module-og-tags/version/2.0.14/' URL could not be accessed: HTTP/2 403
```

When I downgrade composer to version `1.10.26` everything works fine, but I would rather not use that version of composer since it's deprecated.

Weird thing is that I'm able to pull that package with latest Composer outside Docker build. Even when I run `composer install` inside that container everything works.

I suspect that the reason is that [magefan.com](https://magefan.com) does not support HTTP/2. I checked the URL with `is-http2-cli` and it returned that `HTTP/2 is` not supported.

```
× HTTP/2 not supported by https://***:***@magefan.com/repo/packages/download/package/magefan-module-og-tags/version/2.0.14/
```

What I don't understand is why outside of docker build, Composer is able to default to HTTP/1.1 but not in Docker build.

I tried both Debian and Alpine based PHP images.

Is there any way how to force Composer to not use HTTP/2?

Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4.32-fpm-alpine3.15 AS base

...

FROM base AS composer

RUN apk add --no-cache unzip

COPY --from=composer:1.10.26 /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer
# COPY --from=composer:2.0.14 /usr/bin/composer /usr/local/bin/composer

WORKDIR /app

COPY composer.json composer.lock auth.json ./

RUN composer install --no-dev --no-interaction -o

FROM base AS finish

...
```

Comment: Why do you try to use Composer v2.0.14? That version is over a year old. Did you try to run this using a more recent version of Composer?

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried multiple 2.* versions including the latest one with same result.